# where can I find the volume icons

Tags: android, icons

I am making a three states toggle button and I need the first one to be sound on, the second to be vibrate and the third silent where can I find such images or icons?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for the system (android) icons for these you can find them in the Android SDK folder.  In Windows I believe the default location is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\sdk\platforms\android-$VERSION_NUMBER$\data\res\drawable(mdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, etc.)
```

and on a Mac I believe the default location is:

```
Users\$USERNAME$\Android\sdk\platforms\android-$VERSION_NUMBER$\data\res\drawable(mdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, etc.)
```

Comment: It can also be in you AppData directory, for Windows.